# MySQLi изучение

Tags: mysqli, книги

Добрый день! Какие мануалы стоит почитать для изучения mysqli?

Comment: я так понимаю это был порыв изучить что то свежее и модное или страх перед тем что скоро из php вырежут mysql в том виде в каком был. Рекомендую рассмотреть второй аналог для подобных функций - PDO.

Comment: Нет. Это был порыв обезопаситься от SQL Injection

Comment: Увы от SQL инъекций смена обертки не спасает. От них спасают только мозги.

Comment: Увы, но я почти на 99.9% уверен, что mysqli лучше помогает при защите.

Comment: Я на 100% готов утверждать, что PDO не хуже и как минимум на 80% готов утверждать, что мозги намного лучше помогают защите от таких атак нежели любая из прослоек.

Comment: Хм. Я на верняка утверждать не буду. Но ни та не другая не должны обеспечивать защиту, т.к. они не могут знать наверняка передан валидный запрос или это попытка сломать. Об этом может знать только разработчик  конкретного проекта и должен сам распознавать и принимать необходимые меры. Возможно с использованием средств предоставляемых оберткой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- [Использование mysqli](http://php.su/articles/?cat=phpdb&page=010);
- [Улучшенный модуль MySQL (Improved)](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php).

Почитай "Джон Коггзолл-PHP5 Полное руководство". Там есть раздел.

Answer (score 2):

[Оффициальная документация PHP в формате chm](http://ua.php.net/distributions/manual/php_enhanced_ru.chm) -
Справочник функций - Расширение для работы с базами данных - Расширения для работы с базами данных отдельных производителей - mysqli. Там найдешь все функции, а так же примеры кода. Мне этой документации хватило.